# Allocating and initializing big memory space

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I have a function as follow:

```
float* Alocate2DBlankMemoryContinousSpace(int w, int h)
{
    float *matrix = (float*)malloc(w*h*sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i<w*h; i++)
        matrix[i] = 0.0;
    return matrix;
}
```

for allocation vectors in 2D. For small vectors like w=1000 and h=1000 it is work correctly but for much bigger vectors there is a problem with memory Access violation writing location in fact that I have a lot of free memory to be written. How to allocate and initialize big space in continous memory?

Comment: You don't need to zero your own memory, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, which will zero for you, presumably faster than your program could by itself too.

Comment: Can you give a w,h for which it fails? And info on platform/32/64 bit etc. would also be valuable.

Comment: *"but for much bigger vectors there is a problem"* Yes, that's not surprising. Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" until you tell us what *"much bigger"* is.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. I use multiplier increase volume of matrix and I am going to out of memory because I try as follow: int w=1000*multiplier and int h=1000*multiplier.

Comment: Yes, and what value of `multiplier` causes the problem?

Comment: multiplier=10, w=1000, h=1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 1000x1000 `float` (32-bit) buffer will use 4,000,000 bytes (3.8MiB), that should run fine. I'm curious what values fail for you, perhaps `10000x10000` would fail as that would be a **381MiB**-sized buffer, if you're running in a 32-bit process I can see how you might run out of space if you call your function 3 or more times.

Anyway, you've got some bad habits in your code, the first is that you're not checking to see if the allocation succeeded or not, then you're zeroing your own memory when `calloc` would probably be faster. If the allocation failed `malloc` would return `NULL` yet you're still dereferencing the pointer when you zero the memory yourself.

Do this instead:

```
float* matrix = calloc( width * height, sizeof(float) );
if( matrix == NULL ) exit(1); // Bad-allocation, either terminate or fail gracefully and inform the user of the condition.
return matrix;
```

Comment: Depending on platform, int might be != size_t, too. If say you have a weird platform where size_t is 64 bit and int 16 bit, you could run into negative values inside the malloc. At least use unsigned int ;)

Comment: @BitTickler  Yes, the `int i` was most likely the problem. Even a 32-bit int would be insufficient if `w` and `h` are in the 50K range. I love these questions where it's like pulling teeth to get the one piece of information that actually matters.